# Fetching before navigation with multiple components using vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

Trying to figure out what is the best way to fetch some data before navigating to some routes that I have.

My routes are:

```
let routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: require('./views/Home.vue')
    },
    {
        path: '/messages',
        component: require('./views/Messages.vue'),
    },
    {
        path: '/posts',
        component: require('./views/Post.vue'),
    },
    {
        path: '/login',
        component: require('./views/Login.vue')
    },
    {
        path: '/dashboard',
        component: require('./views/Dashboard.vue'),
    }
];
```

For **/messages**, **/posts** and **/dashboard** I want to fetch some data and while doing that show a spinner.

Vue-router docs suggest to use beforeRouteEnter, [Fetching Before Navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-after-navigation)

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    getPost(to.params.id, (err, post) => {
        next(vm => vm.setData(err, post))
    })
}
```

But my question is, must I implement this fetch logic in all my three view components?
Since it's the same data being fetched I don't want to repeat the logic in every component.

The **beforeRouteEnter** isn't called in my root component where I have this `<router-view></router-view>` otherwise I feel that it would be the best place to have this logic.

I'm really new to vue and this one is a really hard nut to crack for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you aware of [`vuex`](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex)? Since you need to share the same data on three different pages, which sounds like a job for `vuex` store. Basically you can import the `store` into your router, and set data in the store instead of on the component, and then you can conditionally fetch the data by checking the status of the data in the store and if the data already exists, don't fetch. Something like the following:

```js
import store from './store'

beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
  if (store.state.post === null) {
    getPost(to.params.id, (err, post) => {
        store.dispatch('setPost', post)
        next()
    })
  }
}
```

Assume your `store` has a state called `post` and action called `setPost`.

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: { post: null },
  actions: {
    setPost ({ commit }, post) {
      // set the post state here
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Vuex sounds really nice,  I'll check it out tnx!  But I still need to have this code on every component to check if I have fetched the data to the store?

Comment: You don't need this to be on the components. The first part sits in the router file where you use `beforeRouteEnter` to conditionally fetch data. The second part sits separately in a `store.js` which acts as a centralized data store for your application, and can be accessed from all components and pages, via the syntax `this.$store`

Comment: beforeRouteEnter seems only to be available in component https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards . Or you mean I put the check in ```beforeEach``` in router file?

Comment: Yeah. That's what I meant to say. Essentially check the route and store state in router with `beforeEach` or if you don't mind set up the logic in each of the three pages then I guess `beforeRouteEnter` is also doable especially if you refactor all the logic into the store action, then all you need to do in the component is `beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) { this.$store.dispatch('getPost', to.params.id) }`